# How can I convert an Overlay into a figure?

Tags: overlay

Now I'm trying to use

```
Show[plota, Epilog->Inset[inset, Scaled->[{0.2, 0.7}]]]
```

operation to insert an inset of a figure, where plota is an Overlay of two plots

```
plota = Overlay[{plotb, plotc}];
```

and then I cannot be successfully inserted in because "Overlay is not a type of graphics" so it cannot be showed.

What should I do to make the inset works?

Comment: `Head[Graphics@Inset@Overlay[{plotA, plotB}]] === Graphics` gives `True`, so a route to convert an `Overlay` into a `Graphics` is to use `Inset` as an intermediate

Answer (score 4):

You can just make everything an [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html), this way you don't even need an underlying `Graphics` object to build on top of.  Using the plots from Mr. Wizard's post,

```
insetA = Overlay[{plotB, plotC}];
insetB = Overlay[{plotA, Graphics@Circle[{0, 0}, .1]}];
Show[Graphics /@ {Inset[insetA, {0, 0}, {0, 0}], 
   Inset[insetB, Scaled[{-.05, -.05}], {0, 0}, 
    Scaled[{.5, .5}], {1, 1}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I just combined two `Overlay` objects using `Show`

Answer (score 2):

As JasonB temporarily commented you can [`Rasterize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize.html) an [`Overlay`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Overlay.html) to convert it into a (rasterized) `Graphics` expression.

```
plotB = Plot[2 Sin[x] + x, {x, 0, 15}, Filling -> Bottom];
plotC = Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Green, Axes -> False];

plotA = Overlay[{plotB, plotC}];

inset = Graphics[{Red, Thick, Dashed, Circle[]}];

Show[Rasterize @ plotA,
 Epilog -> Inset[inset, Scaled[{0.3, 0.6}]]
]
```

[image]

Doing this you will however loose the scalability of (un-rasterized) vector graphics.  You may instead want to `Inset` repeatedly:

```
Show[plotB,
  Epilog -> {
    Inset[plotC, Automatic, Automatic, Scaled[{1, 1}]], 
    Inset[inset, Scaled[{0.3, 0.6}]]
  }
]
```

Comment: Overlay[{}] is my typo, never mind that. And I also post a wrong question... I actually want to ask what if plota is an Overlay? For Show[] cannot show an Overlay.

Comment: @RoderickLee Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: the question is edited

Comment: +1 - I erased the Rasterize because I had the inset rasterized, which made the background opaque and looked bad.  But if you are rasterizing the bottom layer, it's better.